# Tortoise SVN not working from Home internet

Tags: tortoisesvn

"Client SVN not accessible (commit/update) from office Laptop/desktop when connected with home internet. Same client SVN is accessible from personal laptop using internet settings. If we connect the office laptop on office internet and use the office proxy settings, we are also able to access the client SVN. seems some configuration issue with the office laptop/desktop."

Any clue to suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: Not sure what the quotes mean. Is it an error message you're getting in TortoiseSVN or you're just asking a question on behalf of someone else? In any case, Subversion supports several repository access methods. My advice is that you configure an HTTPS server (you've probably done). The rest is actually networking / VPN configuration, far beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: We were able to solve the problem. There was one application running in background which prohibits access to customer svn in office laptop/desktop. Once we kills the application, SVN starts working.